# Jquery - Future Date from now with variables

Tags: jquery, variables, date, time, input

```
$("input").change(function(){

var enteredMonth = $("input[name=month]").val();
var enteredDay = $("input[name=day]").val();
var enteredHr = $("input[name=hour]").val();

var today = new Date();

});
```

I am looking to calculate the exact date & time (ex: 2/14/12 @ 12:13pm) from the date/time of the change() event. I'd like to use input values for months, days, and hours from now. So the user inputs 2 in the month field, 3 in the day field, and 24 in the hours field - I need to calculate the date from now using the variables. The above snippet is what I have this far. Looking for tips on where to go next. Thanks much.

Comment: not hard to search `javacsript compare dates`. Also not hard to search for `javascript Date` and figure out how to create a date object from values you have

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be subtracted in order to know the diferences, you can create a new date using the inputs and then subtract from the current date.

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
var today = new Date();
var myDiffTime = d.getTime() - today.getTime();
```

myDiffTime is the milliseconds between the two dates

---

In order to know a date/time in the future you can add the desired qty of each part with the following approach:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 2);
myDate.setDay(myDate.getDay() + 10);
myDate.setHours(myDate.getHours() + 12);
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correct (or possibly I'm not understanding your comments). Let's say I need to find the time exactly 2 months, 10 days, and 12 hours from now. How would that be done?